# Variable scope into tabs() jQuery UI function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

```
$(function() {

    $("#tabs").tabs({
        beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
            var tab = "";
            tab = ui.newPanel.attr('id');
            if( $('#tab-inserimento').attr('id') === tab ){
                alert("a");
            }else if( $('#tab-ricerca').attr('id') === tab ){
                alert("b");
            }

        }

    });

    apriTab(tab);

});
```

I have a problem with this function. `tab` variable get the id value of the current selected tab, ok.

But, I also need to use this variable for `apriTab()` function. However, there is a scope problem. Like the code was written `apriTab()` can't see the variable. To solve it, I could declare `tab` outside `$("#tabs").tabs({..`.
In this way I would create another problem: `tab = ui.newPanel.attr('id');` it would not work. I'm sure because I debugged with chrome console and the entire function is not execute.

**UPDATE:**

```
$(function() {

$("#tabs").tabs({
    beforeActivate: function (event, ui) { 
        var tab = "";
        tab = ui.newPanel.attr('id');
        if( $('#tab-inserimento').attr('id') === tab ){
            getNotifiche(LIV_NOTIFICA_TAB, AREA_TEMATICA_PAGAMENTI, TAB_GESTIONE);
        }else if( $('#tab-ricerca').attr('id') === tab ){
            getNotifiche(LIV_NOTIFICA_TAB, AREA_TEMATICA_PAGAMENTI, TAB_CONSULTA);
        }
        apriTab(tab);
    }

});

apriTab(tab); //Here, I get an error because tab variable is not visible. But, with this error, the code above of this call works! And, always about this call, if I remove it, nothing works again! How it's possible?!

});
```

Comment: Your `apriTab` call outside the event handler will only ever run once. You can just use the `active` option to get the currently active tab at that point

Comment: @blgt, can you give me an example? Thank you

Comment: if the tab is not visible, then what value do you hope to pass on to the apriTab method?

Comment: There is always a visible tab. I use beforeActive, because when the page is loaded the tab with id #tab-inserimento must be shown for default. So, I don't have this problem.

Comment: so why don't you directly pass that id value to outer apritab method apriTab("tab-inserimento"); or at-least make the tab variable global and initialize it with tab-inserimento

Answer (score 0):

Or may be you have two different variables

```
$(function() {
    var tab = "";
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
            tab = ui.newPanel.attr('id');
            if( $('#tab-inserimento').attr('id') === tab ){
                alert("a");
            }else if( $('#tab-ricerca').attr('id') === tab ){
                alert("b");
            }
        }
    });
    apriTab(tab);
});
```

Comment: The parameter passed to `apriTab()` function must has ui.newPanel.attr('id') value.

Comment: @DavideFruci In that case tab has to have global scope inside the function(){} block

Comment: @DavideFruci " In this way I would create another problem: tab = ui.newPanel.attr('id'); it would not work." Why would it not work?

Comment: Because I debug the function with Chrome console, and when I click on the tab, the debugger does not stop the function in the points where I had the breakpoint (on the if statements). I don't know why..

Comment: @DavideFruci can you put breakpoints before if statement and check if the value of tab is correct or not?